# Left justifying chapter name while chapter number is right justified

Tags: sectioning

Considering the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[avantgarde]{quotchap}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

How can we left justify the chapter name only?

Comment: Where should the chapter number go to then? Left justified to what?

Comment: I simply need chapter number to appear on its default position i.e. on right side of the page while moving the chapter name to left side of the page.

Comment: What does `quotchap` documentation say about this?

Comment: I am not sure about this but even if I remove fillpage package, chapter name and chapter number appear on right side of the page except the overall size of the page is decreased.

Comment: Assuming the chapter name and number fit on the same line, should they in fact be set on the same line? Or do you want to preserve the default vertical positioning, viz., chapter number on a line by itself and *above* the chapter name?

Comment: Yes. I want the default vertical positioning to be the same i..e chapter number on the line above the chapter line. Just the name of the chapter need to be shifted to the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patch the redefined `\@makechapterhead` to have `\raggedright` in the right place:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[avantgarde]{quotchap}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
 {\raggedleft\advance}
 {\raggedright\advance}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is working fine for the above specified test case. But it is not affecting the .tex files included in the main file. Can you please specify those changes as well?

Comment: @Shahzad Sorry, but I don't understand. If you do `\input{file}` and `file.tex` contains `\chapter{Title}`, there should be no difference at all.